# PHP: Retrieve number of days from Calendar Range Period

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

**if**

```
$_POST['SelectedDate1'] = 2013/08/05
```

**and**

```
$_POST['SelectedDate2'] = 2013/08/07
```

How can I set a variable which gives me back the number of days (**2 in this case**) to then echo it as result

I'm looking for a solution that can cover any calendar combination.

Is there any global function in php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
$days = (strtotime($_POST['SelectedDate2']) - strtotime($_POST['SelectedDate1'])) / 86400;
```

example:

```
<?php
$_POST['SelectedDate1'] = '2013/08/05' ;
$_POST['SelectedDate2'] = '2013/08/07' ;
$days = (strtotime($_POST['SelectedDate2']) - strtotime($_POST['SelectedDate1'])) / 86400;

var_export($days);
// output: 2
```

Comment: You'd be better off using the native DateTime to correct for timezone/daylight savings time. :) Additionally, it offers a lot more output possibilities.

Comment: var_export($days) returns me "0"

Comment: @user2635574 copy all the code, then run it, the out put will be `2`.

Comment: Reverse SelectedDate1 and SelectedDat2. Rule of thumb: when the latter it higher, always place it first (`60 - 120 = -60` while `120 - 60 = 60`, thus making `abs()` obsolete).

Comment: @ReSpawN, thank you. What you say makes sense. using `abs()` just to make sure the code will work in case of illegal input.

Comment: @user2635574, OK. Any other question, please feel free to ask here.

Answer (score 6):

I think, in the following Documentation on PHP.net is exactly what you're trying to do.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

In your case:

```
<?php

$first = new DateTime($_POST['SelectedDate1']);
$second = new DateTime($_POST['SelectedDate2']);
$passed = $first->diff($second);

var_dump($passed->format('%R%a days'));
```

For more formats, next to `%R%a`, see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: n/p :) Wanted to avoid confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

I use this function that I've found on this forum but I don't remember where :

```
function createDateRangeArray($start, $end) {
    // Modified by JJ Geewax 
    $range = array();
    if (is_string($start) === true) $start = strtotime($start);
    if (is_string($end) === true ) $end = strtotime($end);
    if ($start > $end) return createDateRangeArray($end, $start);
    do {
    $range[] = date('Y-m-d', $start);
    $start = strtotime("+ 1 day", $start);
    }
    while($start <= $end);
    return $range;
}
```

it returns a range of date as an array, then you just have to get the count

Answer (score 0):

[DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class is created for this:

```
    $date1 = new DateTime('2013/08/05');
    $date2 = new DateTime('2013/08/07');
    $diff = $date1->diff($date2);
    echo $diff->days;
```